# cannot insert data into a new column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

Hi I'm trying to write code for an email to auto update in an interactive grid in Oracle APEX. It keeps saying that my column identifier needs to be defined however it is defined by each table.
[image]

```
select 
t.email into O.email
from Master_Tech_Email t, MASTER_COURSE_OWNER O 
where O.Technology = t.Technology;
```

Comment: Are you trying to update all of the email values in the `master_course_owner` table? Or select a single email for display in your APEX grid? Or something else?

Comment: I am trying to update an email display value in that specific row for when the technology is changed

Answer (score 0):

I think a misunderstanding into clause.

If you want to update email column in MASTER_COURSE_OWNER  table based on Technology column try this

(Because of tags include sql and oracle I am sharing both of it)

For Oracle:

```
UPDATE MASTER_COURSE_OWNER SET EMail = (SELECT Email FROM Master_Tech_Email WHERE Technology = MASTER_COURSE_OWNER.Technology AND ROWNUM = 1)
```

I am putting a live sample for Oracle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a9e06979b1485c4815dbd34f00e98011)

For SQL:

```
UPDATE MASTER_COURSE_OWNER SET EMail = (SELECT TOP(1) Email FROM Master_Tech_Email WHERE Technology = MASTER_COURSE_OWNER.Technology)
```

I am putting a live sample for SQL [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44692334bc12491fb221afc4d4810cf4)

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle, not SQL Server, so the syntax in your update/fiddle isn't valid; and it's unclear what your first statement does - in Oracle at least it won't create a table, and if `emailtable` was a collection type it would need to be a bulk operation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Mr. Alex. 
I realize it  after your comment and added oracle version

Comment: Both of these solutions result in SQL errors where APEX cannot actually read the code.